# how to test a Module in NodeJs without function in it?

Tags: node.js, sinon, chai

I have read and tried many ways to do this,I have a module like below .

```
//echo.js

module.exports = (services, request) => { 
  logger.debug('excecuting');
  return true;
};
```

I want to write unit test for this module using sinon , what i did tried so far is.

```
describe('test', function() {
const echo1 = require('./echo');
var spy1 = sinon.spy(echo1);

beforeEach(() => {
spy1.resetHistory();
  });

it('Is function echo called once - true ', done => {
echo1(testData.mockService, testData.stubRequest); //calling module
spy1.called.should.be.true;
done();
  });
});
```

i get the below output which is failed, though i see my function being called in the output window

```
1) test
   Is function echo called once - true :

  AssertionError: expected false to be true
  + expected - actual

  -false
  +true

  at Context.done (echo_unit.js:84:27)
```

could anyone tell me how to test modules in nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter in this case whether it's a module or just a function.

A function that isn't called as a method can't be spied (also, `describe` function isn't a proper place to place `var spy1 = sinon.spy(echo1)`). This also isn't needed here because it's you who call the function, there's no need to test that it was called.

Since all that `echo` does is calls `logger.debug` and returns `true`, this needs to be tested:

```
it('Is function echo called once - true ', () => {
  sinon.spy(logger, 'debug');
  const result = echo1(testData.mockService, testData.stubRequest);
  expect(logger.debug).to.have.been.calledWith("execute");
  expect(result).to.be(true);
  // the test is synchronous, no done() is needed
});
```